# feed a list of items into a 3-column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say i have a list of boxes to be displayed in a 3-column layout and I want to achieve something like below, where each number represents a box (div) of fixed width.

```
   1 2 3
   4 5 6
   7 8...
```

One way to do so would be to have 3 columns on the page, and divide the objects into 3 lists where the first list contains items 1 4 7 and second list contains items 2 5 8 and so forth and feed each list to each column.

The problem is that my page is dynamic and items might be deleted and created and I want the items to reposition automatically (for example, if 5 were taken out, 6 should go to 5's position, and 7 would take 6's position...)

Is there a straight forward way to do this in CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex could help too : *(hover any li to remove next to test behavior)*

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin:20px;
  padding:20px;
  justify-content:center;
  background:gray;
}
li {
  width:30%;
  border:solid;
  margin:1em 1%;
  background:white
}
/* demo purpose */
li:nth-child(even) {
  color:green;
}
/* remove one li */
li:hover + li {
  position:absolute;
  top:-9999px
}

li {
  counter-increment:linbr;
}
li:before {
  content:counter(linbr);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li> <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>  <li><li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;`

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cfkojpvu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
ul { padding-left: 0;}
li { float: left; width: 30%; list-style: none; background: red; color: #fff; margin: 1%; }
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/g3816wry/1/)

I've made a script to show it works when you delete a random `li` in the list.